# Exchange rate modeling using a system of ODEs

Tags: exchange-rates, international-economics, ode

I am looking for a book that explains exchange rates, capital flows, reserves, trade balance using a system of ordinary differential equations.

An economist by the name of Muller-Plantenberg has [this paper](https://isiarticles.com/bundles/Article/pre/pdf/79576.pdf), which has the level of explanation I was looking for. I could use this paper as is, I am just curious if anyone else, especially in a recent book, with code, data has similar approach to this topic.

Comment: I have not heard of this journal before; doesnt seem to be in the top 1000 (https://ideas.repec.org/top/top.journals.all.htm)

Comment: The classic reference is the Dornbusch 1976 paper, https://www.mit.edu/~14.54/handouts/dornbusch76.pdf

Comment: I am looking for something recent, preferably with Github code and data, something like Tsay's book on time series analysis.

Comment: @ChinG, your link is dead, but the journal has a rank around 200 in IDEAS, depending on the specific ranking. (They spell it with an &.)